# Создать XML на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, xml

Есть таблица на сайте, надо сделать кнопку для её выгрузки в XML.

Вопрос в том, как сделать следующие пункты:

- Создание каркаса на JavaScript,
- Отправка его обработчику (PHP), который и создаст XML.

Пример того, что должно получиться (обычный .xml файл, созданный в MS Excel).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
    <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
     xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
     xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
     xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
     xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
     <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
      <Author>PrabuDeveloper</Author>
      <LastAuthor>Пользователь Windows</LastAuthor>
      <Created>2017-04-21T09:27:10Z</Created>
      <LastSaved>2017-04-21T10:51:43Z</LastSaved>
      <Version>16.00</Version>
     </DocumentProperties>
     <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
      <AllowPNG/>
     </OfficeDocumentSettings>
     <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
      <WindowHeight>12330</WindowHeight>
      <WindowWidth>28800</WindowWidth>
      <WindowTopX>0</WindowTopX>
      <WindowTopY>0</WindowTopY>
      <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
      <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
     </ExcelWorkbook>
     <Styles>
      <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
       <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
       <Borders/>
       <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:CharSet="204" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11"
        ss:Color="#000000"/>
       <Interior/>
       <NumberFormat/>
       <Protection/>
      </Style>
      <Style ss:ID="s62">
       <NumberFormat ss:Format="Percent"/>
      </Style>
      <Style ss:ID="s63">
       <NumberFormat ss:Format="mmm/yy"/>
      </Style>
      <Style ss:ID="s64">
       <NumberFormat ss:Format="dd/mmm"/>
      </Style>
     </Styles>
     <Worksheet ss:Name="Отчет по группе объявлений (9)">
      <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="12" ss:ExpandedRowCount="259" x:FullColumns="1"
       x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
       <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="224.25"/>
       <Column ss:Index="5" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="96.75"/>
       <Column ss:Index="11" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="114"/>
       <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="203.25"/>
       <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Heviz General MSK_SPB</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">627</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">1997</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">1.8</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">220.08</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">15</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">14</Data></Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="Number">2.41E-2</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">14.58</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">0.35</Data></Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="Number">0.2271</Data></Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s63"/>
       </Row>
<!-- ... -->
```

Comment: так что надо на js? добавь пример входных и выходных данных

Comment: как правильно\грамотно создать xml(набросок ,структуру , незнаю как назвать) документ .

Comment: ну так ты покажи, что именно ты хочешь создать

Comment: вообще xml и xls это не одно и то же

Comment: причем тут xls ? где вы это увидели ?

Comment: _Excel.Sheet_ намекает. Собственно эту заглушку и можешь использовать как шаблон

Comment: я та глубоко не разбираюсь , я вижу раcширение xml , и прошу дать совет как грамотно делать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57473/discussion-between-grundy-and-mojlo4huk).